# SSL encrypted connection to MySQL container not possible over AWS elastic load balancer

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, docker, amazon-elb

I am trying to establish a SSL-encrypted connection to a my MySQL Docker service running on a AWS VPC (setup up by the Docker for AWS cloud formation template). The elastic load balancer is configured to redirect port 3306. There is no problem to connect to the container (e.g. by using MySQLWorkbench, mysql-client, ..) as long as SSL is not turned on (adding AWS's own certificates (ACM) or my custom certificates to the ELB listener). In case SSL is enabled, the client starts hanging / freezing, without returning a proper error. I added the ca-certs from ACM, generated my own certificates (with and without additonal key / cert for the client) but nothing seems to resolve my problem.

Now I am well aware of the fact, that this setup is not that usual. I guess the standard way of doing this is to configure the MySQL-Server itself. AFAIK, in this case only the connection between client and ELB is encrypted, but I do not understand why this causes a problem?

I am grateful for answers!

Comment: MySQL simply wasn't designed to run behind that type of load balancer. If you want load balanced MySQL you should look into AWS Aurora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL's client/server protocol, the server talks first.  It advertises its capabilities (including whether it supports SSL).  Then the client requests that the connection switch to SSL mode.  Only then does SSL negotiation take place.

For this reason, it is not possible to offload SSL in front of MySQL.

Your connection hangs because the client is waiting for the initial packet from the server, while the ELB is waiting for the client to start negotiating SSL -- because unlike the MySQL client/server protocol, the client talks first on standard SSL negotiation.

You have to have a certificate on the MySQL Server, and not on the ELB, for this to work.

An AWS *Network* Load Balancer is a more appropriate solution for exposing MySQL, but you still need the SSL cert on the MySQL Server itself.

Comment: Thank you @Michael -sqlbot & Marc B for your anwers - I finally did it the ordinary way, just redirecting the port and doing the configuration on the MySQL server itself.